# React Native Android application does't ask to use geolocation from user

Tags: react-native

In my React Native application I use geolocation. IOS app asks permission for using user geolocation but Android app automatically allows user's geolocation. How can I ask permission for it.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it'll be asked since 6.0.1 (could be wrong). If you want to notify user by asking permission, you need to use *react-native-permissions* for it (https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think accessing location is enabled by default, you have to enable it as described in the [`Geolocation` docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html).

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

To show the dialog asking for the permission on Android M (6.0) and newer, use the [`PermissionsAndroid`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html) module.